# How to collapse specific inbox group when selecting "Inbox" and expand all other groups?

Tags: vba, outlook

My inbox is sorted by Categories. The top-most category displayed are emails I send to myself as reminders.  All other emails are categorized by the company department of the sender.

I would like when I click on Inbox in the Folder Pane, all category groups are expanded in the Reading Pane except for the top-most category.

I researched but I'm not understanding which VBA objects and methods to use.  I also do not know how this code would be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not exposed. If I were you, I'd rather create a search folder for each category that that you want to access separately.